# How to send an osascript command to a Mac via SSH - Dealing with single quotes

Tags: applescript, ssh

I know how to send a command via SSH. For example, I have an old Canon scanner hanging off of a Raspberry Pi. To initiate a scan I can do this:

```
ssh pi@raspsky 'scanimage -x 105 -y 149 --resolution 300 > scan.ppm'
```

However, now I want to send a command from the Pi to the Mac. The command contains single quotes:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Image capture failed!"'
```

But, I need to put single quotes around the entire command. I don't know how to do that. I've tried escaping the single quotes, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do the answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) help?

Comment: Yes. Originally I was horribly confused by that post. But, at your suggestion, I read it again this morning and came up with the answer I posted in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I tested: `zsh -c 'osascript -e "display dialog \"hi\""'`

`osascript -e` doesn't ***need*** single-quotes, and it works fine with double-quotes. Osascript also has good escaping, so I escaped the quotes inside osascript and used single-quotes for the enclosing command. For you it would be:

```
ssh <username>@<Mac-host> 'osascript -e "display notification \"Image capture failed!\"'
```

Testing it on my pi, it works. If you want to make a single command, I'd recommend creating a shell script which contains

```
scanimage -x 105 -y 149 --resolution 300 > scan.ppm || ssh <username>@<Mac-host> 'osascript -e "display notification \"Image capture failed!\"'
```

and running that via SSH on your Mac, as I don't think this would work if you put this inside another set of '', which would occur if you send this entire command over ssh.

Comment: This also works: `pi@raspsky:~ $ ssh mnewman@MrMuscle  'osascript -e '\''display notification "image capture failed"'\'''`

Comment: @user3439894 I'm sorry, stack exchange removed them or I didn't copy correctly. I don't know why. I edited then back in. They did work in the terminal.

Comment: anonymous, RE: "stack exchange removed them or I didn't copy correctly" -- I can assure you that you didn't copy them correctly, as **Ask Different** doesn't trim _code_  +1.

Comment: Does it really matter? It was pretty easy to see the open quote and close it to test the answer.

Comment: @Buadhai, RE: "Does it really matter?" --  Yes! Any posted _code_ that states it works should be abled to be copied and pasted without having to debug errors. I obviously saw the missing quotes, but that's not the point!

Comment: You pointed out the error. He fixed it. At that point you just let it go.